# Converting HTML to DOC with look and feel

Tags: python

Is it by anyway possible to convert HTML pages to word with some basic styling like tables , some colored headers, a few images ? I work with python . Are there any good libraries to mimic the representation as closely as possible ?

Comment: did you try win32com from the pywin32 python extensions for windows?

Comment: You might look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920938/formatted-output-in-openoffice-microsoft-word-with-python

Comment: or [this link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226095/python-html-to-doc-converter?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need [Python for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to do it this way, but I'd do it like this. That way you don't even have to convert it yourself.

```
import win32com.client as win32

ms_word = win32.Dispatch('Word.Application')
ms_doc  = ms_word.Documents.Add('your_website.html')

ms_doc.SaveAs('your_word_doc.doc')

ms_doc.Close()
ms_word.Quit()
```

Comment: So this is only for windows ?

Comment: Yes, I just made that assumption given it was word. What OS are you on?

Comment: On Ubuntu I'd use `AbiWord`. Try `abiword --to=doc filename.odt`